# javafx using AutoCompletion with database

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, controlsfx

i am trying to use AutoCompletion of `controlfx` to myy project and the code is

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(
            textField,
            "Hey", "Hello", "Hello World", "Apple", "Cool", "Costa", "Cola", "Coca Cola");
```

This code can only be used when all list is known but i am trying to connect it with mysql database and codes i used

```
  try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","root");
            String sql="Select * from table";
           Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
 TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(
           textfield,""); 
    while(rs.next()){
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(
            textfield,rs.getString(2));       
}

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

        }
```

but i got a problem that it only show 1 item in Suggestion box although it has multiple match

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, you are rebinding the result for each result. Thus only the last result wins. What you really want is to create a collection or array from the ResultSet entries which you then bind **once** after performing the query.